# HTML: img inside a tag not working

Tags: html

Why is my image not becoming hyperlinked? Here's my HTML code (with links taken out), and the CSS of the div it's in:

```
<div class=bannercontainer>
<a href="(working URL here)" target="_blank"><img src="image.png" width="194" height="67" border="0" /></a></div>
.bannercontainer{ margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto; width:900px; height:500px; margin-top:50px;}
```

Comment: What version of HTML is your doc? Why isn't your class wrapped in double quotes? <div class="bannercontainer">

Comment: DOCTYPE HTML public. The double quotes was just overlooked.

Comment: Which browsers are you finding this in? The code seems to work fine here.

Comment: Chrome. The errant a/img is the App Store Badge. Here's the site live: http://www.unc.edu/~balong/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "clear:both" to `.lowerpart` is a solution, of sorts. But I'd recommend re-writing your HTML. It doesn't need to be so complicated... or filled with errors :-/

Note: `#feature` should be a class (`.feature`), not an ID, as there's many of them in the document.

Tip: Trying verifying your HTML in the future: http://validator.w3.org/

Also maybe getting a book on learning HTML ([Headfirst HTML/CSS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059610197X) couldn't make it much easier) or doing some online training: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Comment: Wow, thanks. Yeah, it's been a few years since I wrote a web page. Why did clear:both applied to lowerpart fix it?

Comment: You have way too many floats going all over the place, and nothing `clear`ing them. The next block element after a `float`ed div should always have `clear:both` in it, if you're not floating it, too.

Comment: You should really do a refresher, you'll just be pulling your hair out at the next hiccup. HTML and CSS are easy, but not when you're trying to feel your way through without a guide. Just my 2c.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class=bannercontainer>
```

needs quotes like this

```
<div class='bannercontainer'>
```

Comment: Not if this is HTML 2, 3 or 4 (not strict).

Comment: @Django - HTML 4 transitional is not likely? In what universe?

Comment: This should not be relevant to the question or (in reality) have an affect on how the browser renders the page. (Although I think your sentiment is right, it's not a 'need')

Comment: just calls em hows I sees em.

Comment: True. I didn't think of HTML 4 Transitional.

Comment: Oh, and just for completeness and because I can't find a real answer to the problem, HTML5 doesn't need quotes on attributes either.

Comment: Double quotes didn't fix anything

Comment: Anyone else got a suggestiong?